failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized
import pygame
import random
import math
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

app = QApplication([])
layot_main = QHBoxLayout()
main_win = QWidget()
first = QPushButton('Запуск')
two = QPushButton('Настройки')
firstt = QPushButton('Запуск')
layot_main.addWidget(first, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
layot_main.addWidget(two, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
layot_main.addWidget(firstt, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
firstt.hide()
timer = 0.5


def nastr():
    first.hide()
    two.hide()
    timer = int(input('Введите время'))
    firstt.show()


def show_on():
    # Инициализация Pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Размеры окна
    width = 800
    height = 600

    # Цвета
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    red = (255, 0, 0)

    # Создание окна
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Эксперимент Резерфорда")

    # Класс для представления атомов
    class Atom(Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
            self.image.set_colorkey(black)  # Устанавливаем прозрачный фон
            pygame.draw.circle(self.image, red, (5, 5), 5)  # Рисуем круглый атом
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (x, y)
            self.velocity = random.uniform(1, 5)
            self.angle = math.radians(340)  # Угол разлета атомов (в данном случае 50 градусов)

        def update(self):
            self.rect.x += self.velocity * math.cos(self.angle)
            self.rect.y += self.velocity * math.sin(self.angle)

            # Проверка столкновений с ядрами
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, nuclei, False):
                self.angle += math.pi  # Изменяем угол движения при столкновении

    # Класс для представления ядер
    class Nucleus(Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
            self.image.set_colorkey(black)  # Устанавливаем прозрачный фон
            pygame.draw.circle(self.image, white, (10, 10), 10)  # Рисуем круглое ядро
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (x, y)

        def check_collision(self):
            for nucleus in nuclei:
                if nucleus != self:
                    distance = math.sqrt((self.rect.x - nucleus.rect.x) ** 2 + (self.rect.y - nucleus.rect.y) ** 2)
                    if distance < 100:
                        angle = math.atan2(self.rect.y - nucleus.rect.y, self.rect.x - nucleus.rect.x)
                        self.rect.x = nucleus.rect.x + int(100 * math.cos(angle))
                        self.rect.y = nucleus.rect.y + int(100 * math.sin(angle))

    # Группы спрайтов для атомов и ядер
    atoms = pygame.sprite.Group()
    nuclei = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Создание ядер
    for _ in range(5):
        x = random.randint(550, 750)
        y = random.randint(100, 400)
        nucleus = Nucleus(x, y)
        nuclei.add(nucleus)

    # Основной цикл программы
    last_spawn_time = time.time() - timer  # Initialize the last spawn time
    while True:
        # Обработка событий
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        # Проверяем, прошло ли полсекунды с момента последнего появления атома
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - last_spawn_time >= 0.1:
            # Создаем новый атом и добавляем его в группу
            x = 400
            y = 300
            atom = Atom(x, y)
            atoms.add(atom)
            last_spawn_time = current_time  # Обновляем время последнего появления

        # Обновление атомов
        atoms.update()

        # Check collision between nuclei
        for nucleus in nuclei:
            nucleus.check_collision()

        # Отрисовка
        screen.fill(black)
        atoms.draw(screen)
        nuclei.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


first.clicked.connect(show_on)
two.clicked.connect(nastr)
firstt.clicked.connect(show_on)

main_win.setLayout(layot_main)
main_win.show()
app.exec_()

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
when I try to update the library:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.13 (from versions: 5.15.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.13

I get an error when I try to update the library, because of which the code does not work and PyCharm suggests reinstalling, which of course does not help.

First, always try to run the code outside of the IDE using a terminal/prompt. Then, what OS?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
